# Optimizing mysql query to find all duplicate entries

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I am running a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `tableA`.`field1`,
                `tableA`.`filed2` AS field2Alias,
                `tableA`.`field3`,
                `tableB`.`field4` AS field4Alias,
                `tableA`.`field6` AS field6Alias
FROM (`tableC`)
RIGHT JOIN `tableA` ON `tableC`.`idfield` = `tableA`.`idfield`
JOIN `tableB` ON `tableB`.`idfield` = `tableA`.`idfield`
AND tableA.field2 IN
  (SELECT field2
   FROM tableA
   GROUP BY tableA. HAVING count(*)>1)
ORDER BY tableA.field2
```

This is to find all the duplicate entries, but now it's taking lot of time for the execution. Any suggestions for optimization?

Comment: Provide your structure, please - and what entries are you treating as duplicates for 3 tables

Comment: `group by tableA. having`... does not look right.

Comment: yeah. But it is finding duplicate entries

Comment: Structure, entries, and also an SQLFiddle would help out the people trying to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to find all duplicates on `field2` in `TableA`.  The first step would be to move the `in` subquery to the `from` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.`field1`, a.`filed2` AS field2Alias,
       a.`field3`, b.`field4` AS field4Alias, a.`field6` AS field6Alias 
FROM tableA a left join
     tableC c
     on c.`idfield` = a`.`idfield` join
     `tableB` b
     ON b.`idfield` = a.`idfield` join
     (SELECT field2 
      FROM tableA
      group by field2 
      having count(*) > 1
     ) asum
     on asum.field2 = a.field2
ORDER BY tableA.field2
```

There may be additional optimizations, but it is very hard to tell.  Your question "find duplicates" and your query "join a bunch of tables together and filter them" don't quite match.  It would also be helpful to know what tables have which indexes and unique/primary keys.

Comment: +1 Nice! Exactly what I realized but you beat me to it:) . Also good mentioning this changes the subquery to a derived table (which does not execute for every row).

Comment: That's great. It's fast.phpmyadmin shows the time info : Showing rows 0 - 29 (1526 total, Query took 0.0242 sec)